# Reproduce this slide - tikz

Tags: beamer, tikz-arrows, tikz-styles, beamer-metropolis

I would like to reproduce the attached slide in beamer. Of course, I don't ask you to make it for me. I'm just wondering if you are aware about which package I should use to make the blue big arrow on top. Any tip is very welcome! I hope this is a reasonable question ;)

[image]

Comment: Have you given it a try yourself? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Please remember that this site is not a `please do this for me` service

Comment: You could probably do the whole thing using a TikZ matrix.

Comment: Thank you for your contributions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The big blue arrow can be made with the TikZ librarys `shapes.symbols` and `chains`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols,chains}

\tikzset{big blue/.style={signal, text=white, fill=blue, font=\sffamily, minimum height=7mm, minimum width=3.5cm},
    my label/.style={fill=violet,circle, text=white, yshift=1pt}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain, node distance=0pt]
\node[on chain, big blue, signal to=east, label={[my label]above:{1}}]{Geometry};
\node[on chain, big blue, signal to=east, signal from=west, label={[my label]above:{2}}]{Preprocess};
\node[on chain, big blue, signal to=east, signal from=west, label={[my label]above:{3}}]{Solve};
\node[on chain, big blue, signal to=east, signal from=west, label={[my label]above:{4}}]{Postprocess};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Sandy!